# testing controller creating new scope error

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6, karma-jasmine

Hi I am new to testing with karma Jasmine. I was trying to create a new scope with `controller.$rootScope.$new();` or even just plain `$rootScope.$new();` but I get an error 
`TypeError: Cannot read property '$new' of undefined`
Here is the relevant code code in the describe block toggle options button I am getting the error (that is the only code I have added besides for injecting rootscope)

```
fdescribe('Online Statements', () => {
    const module = window.module;
    const inject = window.inject;

    beforeEach(module('wbbUiApp'));

    describe('Controller', () => {
        let scope;
        let controller;
        let injectibles;
        let bindings;

        const createController = userDetails => {
            inject(($componentController,
                $window,
                $filter,
                $rootScope) => {

                // The same `$inject` array values listed in `account-activity.controller.js`
                injectibles = {
                    $window,
                    $filter,
                    $rootScope
                };

                // The same bindings listed in `account-activity.component.js`
                bindings = {
                    accountDetails
                };

                controller = $componentController('onlineStatements', injectibles, bindings);
        });
     };
   describe('toggle options button', () => {
        it('should set the scope value to the index', () => {
            scope = controller.$rootScope.$new(); // problem here
            const index = 1;
            controller.toggleOptions(index)
            expect(scope.activeRow).toEqual(index)
        })

    })

});
```

this might be something simple as I am just starting. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
describe('Online Statements', () => {
    beforeEach(module('wbbUiApp'));

    let controller;

    beforeEach(()=>{
        inject(($injector)=> {

        const createController = userDetails => {
            inject(($componentController) => {
                let bindings = {
                    accountDetails
                };

                controller = $componentController('onlineStatements', {}, bindings);
        });
     });
   describe('toggle options button', () => {
        it('should set the scope value to the index', () => {
            controller.$onInit()
            const index = 1;
            controller.toggleOptions(index)
            expect(controller.activeRow).toEqual(index)
        })

    })

});
```

As u see you do not need to inject anything manually in your case. You should inject `$scope` only if you have direct dependency on in in component controller.
You may want to inject mock for $window sometimes.